# Perl array get value outside loop

Tags: perl

I have created 1 script in which I am storing existing records in an array and then comparing the record with latest file record and if it exists remove the records from array.
Now I am able to compare and print my record but when i am trying to debug/print those remaining list at last. Once all the loops gets closed it's throwing error like requires a global syntax. Which means script is unable to read remaining list which is present in array outside the array.

For example:
I have 100 records which I put in an array. now when new record process it will look if the value matched in an array it will remove the record from array. So at last which ever records matches it will be removed and remaining_record array will be remained with those record which does not exists in new record file.

```
if ( grep { $new_record eq  $Current_record } @array ) {
  DEBUG( "DEBUG: record found in existing array" );
  my @remaining_record = splice(@array, $new_record, 1);
}
```

Now when I am trying to debug remaining record at the end of the script , script is looking for global variable and looks empty.

```
my @remaining_record;
my $size = @remaining_record;
for ($n=0; $n < $size; $n++) {
    DEBUG( "DEBUG: Remaining records $remaining_record[$n][0]" );
}
```

Comment: Global symbol "@remaining_record" requires explicit package name at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @remaining_record;
my $size = @remaining_record;
```

Either remove `my` from `@remaining_record;` Otherwise it will create new empty array with name `@remaining_record`.

Or assign the old array with remaining data to `remaining_record` like

```
my @remaining_record = @array_with_remaining_data;
```

---

Modify your program like below.

```
my @remaining_record;
if ( grep { $new_record eq  $Current_record } @array ) {
  DEBUG( "DEBUG: record found in existing array" );
  @remaining_record = splice(@array, $new_record, 1);
}

my $size = @remaining_record;
for (my $n=0; $n < $size; $n++) {
    print "DEBUG: Remaining records $remaining_record[$n]";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have tried both the ways .Script is not taking outside loop @remaining_record; without my. Global symbol "@remaining_record" requires explicit package name at... Hope you get my point .I want to debug the list at last once all data gets processed and I want to print remaining list.

Comment: Declare `my @remaining_record;` outside the loop, so that its scope is not limited to your `if` block.

Comment: Provide your complete script. I'll see where else is the issue.

Comment: Even I have tried using my in front of n  "for (my $n " but again same message .. :(

Comment: Provide your complete script. You are doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: You are welcome. Read [this](http://perlmaven.com/global-symbol-requires-explicit-package-name) to know about the error you were getting.